# Hide/show status bar for specific view controllers in PageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` that contains 3 view controllers. I want to hide the status bar for the first 2 view controllers and show the status bar for the last view controller. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the delegate of your PageViewController, add this.

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    PageContentViewController *controller = self.pageViewController.viewControllers[0];
    if (controller.pageIndex == 2) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed
{
    if (completed) {
        PageContentViewController *controller = self.pageViewController.viewControllers[0];
        NSUInteger pageIndex = controller.pageIndex;

        // only update status bar when transition is between page 2 and page 3
        if (pageIndex == 1 || pageIndex == 2) {
            [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason when I try to access `self.pageViewController.viewControllers` in `prefersStatusBarHidden`, it returns nil. Any idea why?

Comment: Firstly you can do nil check on self.pageViewController, if it is nil, then you have to find where is your pageViewController, and put the method in the controller that create your pageViewController.